# Wordpress shows permanent loop redirect after upgrading from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache-2.4, httpd

I've upgraded my Apache 2.2 web server to 2.4 today and then some Wordpress installations started to get infinite loops from non-www to www and from www to non-www :(

Removing .htaccesss didn't helped.

How to solve this ? Example domain config:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=1

ServerAdmin webmaster@internet.az.pl

ServerName internet.az.pl

ServerAlias www.internet.az.pl

DocumentRoot "/home/admin2/komputery"

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.shtml index.htm index.pl index.py index.cgi index.rb default.htm Default.aspx Default.asp

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/admin2/internet.az.pl/cgi-bin/"

<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        Alias /internet.az.pl.0fake "/home/admin2/komputery/internet.az.pl.0fake"
        #FastCGIExternalServer "/home/admin2/komputery/internet.az.pl.0fake" -host 127.0.0.1:52474 -idle-timeout 300 -pass-header Authorization
        FastCGIExternalServer "/home/admin2/komputery/internet.az.pl.0fake" -socket /opt/configs/php-fpm/sock/admin2.sock -idle-timeout 300 -pass-header Authorization
        AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp .php
        Action application/x-httpd-fastphp /internet.az.pl.0fake
        <Files "internet.az.pl.0fake">
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !internet.az.pl.0fake
        </Files>
</IfModule>

<Directory "/home/admin2/komputery/">
        AllowOverride All
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
                Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        Options +ExecCGI
        <FilesMatch \.(cgi|pl)$>
                SetHandler cgi-script
        </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
        php_admin_value sendmail_from "internet.az.pl"
        Include /home/kloxo/client/admin2/prefork.inc
</IfModule>

<Location "/">
        Allow from all
        Options -Indexes -FollowSymlinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/admin2:/tmp:/usr/share/pear:/var/lib/php/session/:/home/kloxo/httpd/script:/home/kloxo/httpd/disable/:/usr/bin"
        </IfModule>
</Location>

CustomLog "/home/httpd/internet.az.pl/stats/internet.az.pl-custom_log" combined
ErrorLog "/home/httpd/internet.az.pl/stats/internet.az.pl-error_log"
```

and also httpd.conf:

```
   ServerTokens Prod

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

# MR -- must be disable here because can not overrite! -- importance for proxy-to-apache
# Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel error

<IfModule log_config_module>
        ## MR -- change %h to %a to fix mod_remoteip issue
    LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    #AddHandler type-map var

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

Alias /error/ "/home/kloxo/httpd/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    <IfModule mod_include.c>
        <Directory "/home/kloxo/httpd/error/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options IncludesNoExec
            AddOutputFilter Includes html
            AddHandler type-map var
            <IfVersion < 2.4>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
            </IfVersion>
            <IfVersion >= 2.4>
                Require all granted
            </IfVersion>
                LanguagePriority en es de fr
            ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
        </Directory>

        #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
        #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
        #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
        #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html

        ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
        ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
        ErrorDocument 501 /error/501.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html
        ErrorDocument 504 /error/504.html
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in nginx - changing line:

```
proxy_set_header X-Host $var_domain;
```

to

```
proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
```

fixed the problem

Comment: Can you mark your answer as valid ?

Answer (score 0):

First... stop using `IfModule` on bits that aren't optional.  (not sure what is or is not required)  They're only useful if you have a fall-back way of recovering if that module doesn't exist or isn't loaded.  Otherwise, apache will start without error... despite the fact that 90% of your config won't actually be loaded.

A quick way to test and ultimately fix... is to remove all of the `IfModule` statements... and then restart apache.  You'll almost certainly get errors.  Read the error logs.  Look at what errors you get... (i.e. can't load blah blah) and enable/install/rebuild the necessary modules that are required to make your site work.

Comment: It's a part of larger config for many options like mod_ruid2, mod_suphp etc.

Comment: That's fine.  That doesn't invalidate my answer.  If it's not optional... you should error rather than permit apache to load.  IfModule silences those errors... which is bad.

Comment: OK. Does it matter if I use nginx as reverse proxy before apache ? It was working well before upgrade to apache 2.4.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference.  As long as your nginix server is behaving properly... it won't affect Apache.  (and vise-versa)

Comment: I just found all my .htaccess redirections from www to non-www also does not work, but no redirect loop.

Comment: is mod_rewrite installed/enabled?

Comment: Yes it is. All is working, but no redirections ;(

Comment: It ended restoring Apache 2.2 ;(